# Filesize with SWFUpload and Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, swfupload

I'm currently using SWFUpload to upload files to my S3 bucket.  And it's working great.

I'm using the script from a website here: http://www.anedix.com/news/article/50

Again, the upload to my S3 works fine, however, I've been running into an issue when attempting to upload larger files.  It seems that I cannot upload anything over 50MB.  I have tried this from both my webhost and locally, using my local testing environment.

My question is this:  When uploading with SWFUpload, it should be going straight to Amazon S3, correct?  If so, then PHP settings such as MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE should not affect it?  (Even though in my local environment, I've set it to 1024MB.)

Essentially, what the script does is, shows that it's uploading the file (it takes the appropriate amount of time), redirects to the success page, and does not throw any errors.

Any ideas on why this would be happening, or how I can troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file_size_limit is also a param of SWFUpload ... have you checked it ?
also consider a 30% more as the content posted be encoded

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't quite it, but you got me on the right track.  Apparently, when setting up the post parameters for S3, I overlooked that content-length-range was set to, guess what, 50MB.  Thanks!